# re.split not giving last character of the regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
n='Sumit,raj. ramesh is good. calm down'
re.split(r'[a-z0-9]\.',n)
```

for the above string n and regular expression it gives me the below result.

```
['Sumit,ra', ' ramesh is goo', ' calm down']
```

I don't know why its truncating the last character of the word.I want to split the sentences at dot but I want full text before the dot which I am unable to get. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The text you split *on* is not included in the output. You want to split on *just* the `.`:

```
re.split(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])\.' ,n)
```

This uses a positive look-behind assertion (`(?<=...)` to only match `.` if it is preceded by lowercase letters or digits, but most importantly does not include those letters or digits itself in the match.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> n = 'Sumit,raj. ramesh is good. calm down'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=[a-z0-9])\.' ,n)
['Sumit,raj', ' ramesh is good', ' calm down']
```